# Can any one suggest a Dojo and JSON book?

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

Can any one here suggest a good Dojo and JSON book or a site for tutorials please for a graduate student.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can any one suggest the edition number too please

Comment: [Javascript: the Good Parts, 1st Ed](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742)  [Javascript: The Definitive Guide, 6th Ed.](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-Activate-Guides/dp/0596805527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I own David Flanagan's Most Excellent "Javascript: The Definitive Guide" and I agree - it's a must-have for any Javascript developer.

... however ...

The one framework Flanagan covers is jQuery (not Javascript).

I'd recommend the on-line IBM Redbooks for Dojo and JSON:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ground/index.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/training/kp/wa-kp-dojo/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-rest1/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/wa-jsonreststore/

Etc. etc

And, even more than Flanagan ("The Rhino Book"), I'd *very* strongly recommend Douglas Crockford's "Javascript: The Good Parts" as a must-have for every Javascript developer:

- [http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

Comment: Does Douglas Crockford's book include Dojo and JSON?

Comment: Hi - 1) Rhino Book (Flanagan: Javascript Definitive Guide) I own both the 2nd edition (yes!) and I just bought the 6th Edition.  The 6th Edition is the current edition.  2) No, Crockford doesn't cover Dojo (neither does Flanagan!).  But Crockford's the guy who *invented* JSON.  And he covers it extensively in the book.  The the *real* value of "JS: The Good Parts" is it shows you how to effectively *think* in Javascript (as opposed to just giving you syntax).  IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101996) will teach you everything you need to know (and more) about JSON, and will prepare you for using frameworks like Dojo, Mootools, jQuery... etc.

Comment: Would you suggest any edition?

Comment: I've only read the 2006 publication, but I'm sure the 2011 is great too. There is also is also a book in that series for Dojo, if you want to dive right into the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't really recommend reading a book since you can get very close to the same content online if you know how to look for it, but if you insist, the definitive guide books are always very helpful (you'll need to purchase two off them though to get info about dojo and json):

[http://www.amazon.com/Dojo-Definitive-Guide-Matthew-Russell/dp/0596516487](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516487)

[http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-Activate-Guides/dp/0596805527/ref=pd_sim_b_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805527)

Comment: Also very, very definitely [Javascript: The Good Parts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596517742)  IMHO...

Comment: ^This is a good suggestion as well